# How to determine if an input in EditText is an integer?

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

Hi I'm a newbie in Android Programming.

I'm trying to build an activity which includes an `edittext` field and a `button`. When user type in an integer, the button will lead them to the next activity. However I do not if there's a way to check the type of user's input.

Anyone can help me? Thank you very much！

Comment: I find a line of code on the internet :

Comment: myEdit.getText().getClass().equals(Integer.TYPE)    /// However, after playing with my code, I found out edittext actually return a datatype of Editable

Comment: you can use `TextWather` to get what user Enter in EditText, have you try that?

Comment: And I do not know how to check the type of input. Is 1 represented as a string? CharSequence? Int?

Comment: Hi Henry, after looking up the documentation of TextWatcher, I believe it can not solve my problem because it is used to monitor Text change of editable.  But Thank you anyway!

Comment: You can also modify your EditText field to accept only integers - so there's no need for additional validation. Just add <EditText android:numeric="integer" ..../> to your XML.

Comment: Hi evilone, I have thought of this idea. However, my intention is that, if user input an integer, it goes to another activity. But if it types in a text, it will print out error message.

Comment: Did not see a point to throw a exception when there's no need to do that :) I think you're mad to your users.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Update:**

You can control the EditText to only accept numbers

```
<TextView 
.
.
.
android:inputType="number"
/>
```

or check it programmatically

In Kotlin

```
val number = editText123.text.toString().toIntOrNull() 
val isInteger = number != null
```

---

In Java

```
String text = editText123.getText().toString();
try {
   int num = Integer.parseInt(text);
   Log.i("",num+" is a number");
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   Log.i("",text+" is not a number");
}
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that any number that is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` will return false.  If you would like to check if the input consists only of digits, the correct answer is TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(CharSequence str).

Comment: There is always a performance overhead with try-catch. That's the reason it is recommended to avoid exception catching.

Comment: You mean EditText rather than TextView

Answer (score 54):

Since API level 1, Android provides an helper method to do just that (no need to use regex or catching exception) : [TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(CharSequence str)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isDigitsOnly%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
boolean digitsOnly = TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(editText.getText());
```

Note that this method returns **true** with empty String : [Issue 24965](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24965)

Comment: This will return false for floats like 0.25

Comment: :( stuck at `Note that this method returns true with empty String : Issue 24965`

Answer (score 10):

If you whant EditText accept only numbers you cant specify `android:inputType="number"` in layout file.

Comment: Much better, cleaner and logical approach. android:inputType helps in setting various filters as well based on UX.

Comment: But the user can paste text into the Edittext, which might lead to NumberException crash

Comment: @CWilliams EditText with `android:inputType="number"` will accept only numbers on paste. So if user paste `Some123Text` then only `123` will be pasted.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `TextWatcher` for `EditText` to get value of every change in `EditText`.You need to add interface of TextWatcher in your Activity.

```
 mEditText.addTextChangedListener(Your Class Name.this);
```

on in method of TextWatcher

```
     @Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    Log.v("Log_tag", "After TextChanged" + s.toString());

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    Log.i("Log_tag", "Before TextChanged" + s.toString());

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    Log.e("Log_tag", "ontext Changed" + s.toString());
    //you can match here s with number or integer 
             if(isNumeric( s.toString())){
                      //it is number     
               }
    }


 public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
 {
    return str.matches("-?\\d+(.\\d+)?");
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for introducing me this incredible method. I believe it will be future usage for me! Thank yo :D

Answer (score 4):

Following code can be used to determine digits,

```
boolean isDigits = TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(edtDigits.getText().toString());
```

However since this method returns true with empty String as well so you can put a validation for empty string as follows,

```
public boolean isDigits(String number){ 
   if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(number)){
       return TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(number);
   }else{
       return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

You need to add the properties  `android:nextFocusDown="@+id/nextedittext_id"` and 
         `android:singleLine="true"` in your edittexts.

For example:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/ed2"
         android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ed1" />
```

And add the following code in your activity:

```
 editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String value=s.toString();
                    if(isNumeric(value)){
                        if(Integer.parseInt(value)>=100){
                            editText1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                            editText1.setFocusable(false);
                        }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
        editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                editText1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                editText1.setFocusable(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

isNumeric method is as same as above:

```
 public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
    {
        return str.matches("-?\\d+(.\\d+)?");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a much cleaner solution,which checks if the string is any type of  number including `integer`, `float`, `long` or `double`.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

Boolean isNumber;

try {
    BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal(theStingToCheck);
    isNumber = true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    isNumber = false;
}
```