# Restrict edit text input type as a character on button click

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` in which I am input a 10 digit mobile number after scanning a QR scan. Sometimes I get characters in the `EditText`. In this case I would like to show an error as a `Toast` message as "character not accepted".

This `Toast` will pop on button click. How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(CharSequence str)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isDigitsOnly%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!yourEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            boolean digitsOnly = TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(yourEditText.getText());
            if (!digitsOnly) {
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "Characters are not accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "Please fill the field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

});
```

Please not that this method returns `true` with empty String : [Issue 24965](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24965)

See the original SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120212/how-to-determine-if-an-input-in-edittext-is-an-integer).